# Getting Base Content of Selected Node

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I am using **Syncfusion WPF Controls**.  I have created a project that displays a **Radial Tree Diagram**.

I'm trying to access the base values listed under Content on the bottom of the picture(Link, LinkID, ParentID, etc).

Picture:

[image]

Looking at the `NodeSelected` event, When I run `node.Content.GetType().ToString()`, I get my base class model which contains the properties that I want to access.

So I'm not really sure how to get from selecting the Node, to getting the properties of the base class that is the data for the Node.

Hopefully that all makes sense, I'm self taught.

Here is my MainWindow Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using Syncfusion;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Diagram.Layout;
using Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Diagram;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Link_Map.Classes;
using Syncfusion.SfSkinManager;
using Syncfusion.Windows.Shared;
using Syncfusion.Windows.Tools.Controls;
using Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Diagram.Controls;

namespace Link_Map
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        DirectedTreeLayout tree = new DirectedTreeLayout();
        ObservableCollection<Node> nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        ObservableCollection<Connector> connects = new ObservableCollection<Connector>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitDiagram();
            controller.AddRoot();
            Link_Grid.ItemsSource = controller.viewmodel.Links;
            SkinStorage.SetVisualStyle(this, "Blend");
            //nodes.ElementAt(0).IsSelected = true;
        }

        private void InitDiagram()
        {
            controller.Init();
            lmWindow.Nodes = nodes;
            lmWindow.Connectors = connects;
            DataSourceSettings settings = new DataSourceSettings();
            settings.DataSource = controller.viewmodel.Links;
            settings.ParentId = "ParentID";
            settings.Id = "LinkID";
            settings.Root = "0";
            lmWindow.DataSourceSettings = settings;
            settings.DataSource = controller.viewmodel.Links;
            (lmWindow.Info as IGraphInfo).ItemAdded += MainWindow_ItemAdded;
            (lmWindow.Info as IGraphInfo).ItemSelectedEvent += NodeSelected;

            lmWindow.LayoutManager = new LayoutManager()
            {
                Layout = new RadialTreeLayout()
            };



            (lmWindow.LayoutManager.Layout as RadialTreeLayout).HorizontalSpacing = 10;
            (lmWindow.LayoutManager.Layout as RadialTreeLayout).VerticalSpacing = 35;



            //lmWindow.Tool = Tool.SingleSelect;
            //lmWindow.Tool = Tool.ZoomPan;
            lmWindow.Menu = null;
            lmWindow.ScrollSettings.ScrollLimit = ScrollLimit.Diagram;
            lmWindow.DefaultConnectorType = ConnectorType.Line;
            lmWindow.PageSettings.PageBorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);


            SelectorViewModel svm = (lmWindow.SelectedItems as SelectorViewModel);
            svm.SelectorConstraints = svm.SelectorConstraints & ~(SelectorConstraints.QuickCommands|SelectorConstraints.Resizer);




            //lmWindow.Constraints = SelectorConstraints.QuickCommands;

            //lmWindow.Constraints = lmWindow.Constraints & ~(GraphConstraints.Draggable | GraphConstraints.Selectable);


    }

        public void NodeSelected(object sender, DiagramEventArgs e)
        {
            Node node = (e.Item as Node);
            string ders = node.Content.GetType().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(ders);
        }

        private void Metro_Theme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SkinStorage.SetVisualStyle(this, "Metro");
        }

        private void Blend_Theme_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SkinStorage.SetVisualStyle(this, "Blend");
        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                controller.AddLink();
            }
            lmWindow.LayoutManager.Layout.UpdateLayout();
        }

        //https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/127392/how-to-fire-event-on-sfdiagram-node-selection
        //Apply Node and Connector Style
        private void MainWindow_ItemAdded(object sender, ItemAddedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Item is INode)
            {
                (args.Item as INode).UnitWidth = 10;
                (args.Item as INode).UnitHeight = 10;
                (args.Item as INode).ContentTemplate = this.lmWindow.Resources["contentTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            }
            else if (args.Item is IConnector)
            {
                SolidColorBrush solid = new SolidColorBrush();
                solid.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 186, 186, 186);
                (args.Item as IConnector).TargetDecoratorStyle = this.Resources["style"] as Style;
            }
        }

        private void Link_Grid_GridPasteContent(object sender, Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid.GridCopyPasteEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my question but I have no idea why it works.

I'm self taught so I just try everything I can think of until it works.  I was able to get the base class content I wanted by:

```
public void NodeSelected(object sender, DiagramEventArgs e)
{
    Node node = (e.Item as Node);
    string ders = ((Link_Map.Classes.Links)(((System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)(node)).Content)).link;
    Console.WriteLine(ders);
}
```

Whereas the `(node)).Content)).link` was the property I wanted, I can now access any of the base class properties from here.

If anyone has a better way, please post!

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: “Need to get the Content Properties of the Selected Node”.

Way 1: Casting:
To perform a cast, specify the type that you are casting to in parentheses in front of the value or variable to be converted. We have provided a code example to represent this. Please refer to the code example as below.

Way 2: Iterate the properties via foreach_Reflection:
GetProperties method(FrameWork) is used to get the class model Properties, in that we have find the property values. Please refer to the code example as below.

Code Example:

```
//ItemSelectedEvent
(diagram.Info as IGraphInfo).ItemSelectedEvent += MainWindow_ItemSelectedEvent;

void MainWindow_ItemSelectedEvent(object sender, DiagramEventArgs args)
{
    INode node = args.Item as INode;
    //Way 1:casting
    string des = (node.Content as Employee).EmpId.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(des);

    //Way 2: Iterate the Propeties via foreach
    foreach(var prop in node.Content.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        string des= prop.GetValue(node.Content).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(des);
    }
}
```

Here, diagram is an instance of SfDiagram and Employee is the Base Class.

Comment: Thanks Keer, this solution appears to be cleaner than mine.  Things like this should be in the Syncfusion documentation.